# Is there an Erase for dojo's gfx surface routines?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm using Dojo's gfx routines to draw some shapes onto a div, and other than `surface.clear()`, is there a way to clear or erase just part of the surface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: no. Remember that this a vector graphics with a scene graph. It doesn't operate in term of frame buffers or pixels => it doesn't support a notion of erasing areas.

What you can do it:

- clear the whole surface (surface.clear())
- mask part of the surface with a rectangle or any other suitable shape or shapes — just put it on top of other shapes.
- selectively delete unneeded shapes